# How to recive JSON data from odoo controller to a specific js file (ExtJS)

Tags: javascript, json, model-view-controller, odoo, bryntum-scheduler

I want to add a bryntum schedule (ExtJS framework) to my odoo module but I have problem with transferring data from and to its js file

my controller :

```
@http.route('/testjs', type="json", auth='public', website=True)
    def test(self):    
    return [{'name': 'amor', 'age': '20'},           
           {'name': 'james', 'age': '21'}]
```

and the js file is part which receives data:

```
 var resourceStore = new Sch.data.ResourceStore({   
         model   : 'Sch.model.Resource'});
 
 resourceStore.loadData([  //static data for test  
     {        Id      : 'a',        Name    : 'Rob'    },    
     {        Id      : 'b',        Name    : 'Mike'    }]);
```

note: I think I should use a proxy, but I don't know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like

```
$.getJSON('/testjs?',
    function(data) { ... }
);
```

for more info http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: the probleme that it's not a JQuery it's another js framework called ExtJS

Comment: that's no problem because in the client side of odoo you will find jquery already loaded & you can parse any data you receive to ExtJS as it all javascript